# comments splitting into multiple lines in RMarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

I'm writing a document in RMarkdown, and sometimes I want to have comments in my code chunks that show in the PDF, like this:

```
vector <- 1:4
# finds the mean of these values
mean(vector)
## [1] 2.5
```

However, when I knit the PDF (or HTML document), it breaks the comment up into one-word lines, like this:

```
vector <- 1:4
# finds
# the
# mean
# of
# these
# values
mean(vector)
## [1] 2.5
```

This is really annoying, and it makes my documents way longer than they need to be. How can I fix it?

**EDIT: updated all packages; here's the session info:**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] abind_1.4-5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] backports_1.0.5 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.2   htmltools_0.3.5 tools_3.3.1     yaml_2.1.14     Rcpp_0.12.9     stringi_1.1.2  
 [9] rmarkdown_1.3   knitr_1.15.1    stringr_1.1.0   digest_0.6.12   evaluate_0.10
```

Comment: Not reproducible for me (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), RStudio 1.0.136, R 3.3.2

Comment: For me neither (mac). Please update all relevant packages. Post your session info (`sessionInfo()`).

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer I updated all the packages and added session info. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, not reproducible for me on Win 8 w/ latest Rstudio and R 3.3.2

Comment: Is this just a bad question and I should delete it? I wasn't totally sure it would be on-topic.

Comment: What's the output of `opts_chunk$get()`? It might be the `tidy` options

Comment: @scoa I had `knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=12),tidy=TRUE)` and taking out the width cutoff (or increasing it enough) fixes things. Thank you! Want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be caused by `knitr`/`formattR`'s code tidying, with a `width.cutoff` set too small. You can check your [chunk options](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#chunk_options) with:

```
opts_chunk$get()
```

And maybe set a larger `width.cutoff`; `formatR` will try to make sure no line in your code has a higher number of character than this:

```
opts_chunk$set(tidy=T‌​RUE,
    tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=60))
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know what the units for `width.cutoff` are?

Comment: I think it's a number of characters